# How does finite linear combinations of the $x_n$'s looks like?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, normed-spaces

> Let $X$ be a normed linear space and let $\{x_n\}\subseteq X$. Prove that $x\in X$ is the limit of finite linear combinations of the $x_n$'s iff $Lx=0$ for all continuous linear functionals $L$ on $X$ such that $Lx_n=0$ for all $n$.

My problem is how do we define finite linear combinations of a sequence? Is it again a sequence? And how does its general term looks like? How can we imagine a limit? Is it like limit point? Is there anyone who can help me to understand it? I cannot even start the proof without understanding it.

Comment: If $X$ is over a field $F$, then the set of all finite linear combinations of $\{x_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is $\{ \sum_{j \in J} \alpha_j x_j \in X \colon J \subset \mathbb{N} \textrm{ finite subset and } \alpha_j \in F \}$.

Comment: @msteve: Thanks. Then meaning of the limit is limit point. Isn't it?

Comment: If the set of finite linear combinations that I defined above is $Y$, then a limit point of the finite linear combinations is just a limit point of the set $Y$ in the topological sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a basic application of the Hahn-Banach theorem.

Let's call $S = \mathrm{span} \lbrace x_n \rbrace$

if $x$ is in $S$, it's finished. Let's suppose $x \not\in S$

Let's define the function $p(x) = \inf_{y\in S} \|x-y\|$

$p$ is positive homogen and subadditive.

Now suppose $p(x) =\epsilon > 0$. Let's define a linear functionnal $\phi$ on $\mathrm{span} \left( \lbrace x_n \rbrace \cup \lbrace x \rbrace \right)$ such that :

$\phi(x)=\epsilon$ and $\phi(x_n) = 0$

As $\phi$ is dominated by p on this space, by Hahn-Banach, there exist a linear extension $\psi$ on the whole space $X$ such that $\phi(y) = \psi(y)$ and $\psi(y)\leq p(y)$

But that would mean that there exist a linear functionnal that has value 0 on S, but value $\epsilon$ on x.

This means p(x) = 0 and there exist a sequence of elements of S that approach x as close as you want

Comment: How do you show that the hypothesis $\phi(y)\leq p(y)$ for all $y\in$ span $(\{x_n\}\cup \{x\})$. I get the other way round.

Comment: Let $y\in \mathrm{span} \left( \lbrace x_n \rbrace \cup \lbrace x \rbrace \right)$. Then $y = \lambda x + z$, with $z\in \mathrm{span} \left( \lbrace x_n \rbrace \right)$. And you have $$p(y) = \inf_{u\in S} \|u-y\| = \inf_{u\in S} \|(u-z)+\lambda x\|$$ but $u-z\in S$, so $$p(y) = \inf_{u'\in S} \|u'-\lambda x\|$$ $$p(y)= \lambda \inf_{u'\in S} \|\frac{u'}{\lambda}- x\|$$ $$p(y)= \lambda \inf_{u''\in S} \|u''- x\| = \lambda p(x)$$But on the other hand, $\phi(y) = \phi(z)+\lambda\phi(x) = \lambda\epsilon\leq p(y)$

Comment: Here don't we have to show that $\phi$ is linear?

Comment: No need, it's defined this way. You just have to define the value for each vectors of a basis of $\mathrm{span} \left( \lbrace x_n \rbrace \cup \lbrace x \rbrace \right)$. The basis is composed of vectors from S, and x, and we know the value of $\phi$ on each of these vectors.

Comment: One last question: In order to use the given fact, $\psi$ should be continuous(or bounded). How does this imply?

Comment: Oh, indeed, didn't talk about this. $\psi$ is bounded because $\psi(y) \leq p(y) \leq \|y\|$. Indeed, as $0\in S$, $\inf_{u\in S}\|u-y\| \leq \|0-y\|$